# Branch of incomplete gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, branch-cuts

The incomplete gamma function is defined as follows:

$$
\Gamma(s,z)=\int_z^{\infty}t^s e^{-t}\frac{dt}{t}, \qquad Re(s)>0, \quad z\in \mathbb C
$$

Since $t^s$ is a multi-valued function, this function must be multi-valued. In particular, for $z=-2$, it can be different path to $\infty$. For example, $z=-2+iy$ and $z=-2-iy$, $y\geq 0$.

What is the standard choice of the path, and of the branch cut? Mathematica calculate the value of $\Gamma(3/2,-2) \approx 0.886227 + 7.10586i$. Which choice coincide with this result?

Comment: See the Wikipedia page. If we use $\gamma^*$, it remains to choose a branch of $z^s$. Note that continuing $\Gamma(s, z)$ from $z > 0$ along a circle around $z = 0$ is not the same as substituting a different branch of $t^s$ into the integral. The branch you're considering coincides with integrating the principal value of $t^s$ over the horizontal ray $[z, \infty)$ for $z \in \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$ (note that the integral over $[z, \pm i \infty)$ may diverge), with the value of $\Gamma(s, z)$ for $z < 0$ chosen as the limit from above.

Comment: Thank you maxim